# Segfault on openssl RSA_public_encrypt() in C

Tags: c, openssl, rsa

I have been trying to encrypt a test string using openssl's `RSA_public_encrypt` but it results to segfault in every way I tried to run it.

I tried checking if the RSA key I am reading from the pem file is valid using BIO and it returned the public key properly with correct key and exponent size.

I had initially tried using `PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY` which didn't work out. I am not entirely sure about the difference between that and `PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey`, so if someone can shed some light on this.

Also, before trying out `BIO` I used the regular the FILE structure and the functions that correspond to that and it kept giving me segfaults and I wasn't able to check if the correct RSA key was loaded either. Not sure if that's related.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/conf.h>

int main()
{

  RSA *rsa;
  rsa = RSA_new();
  BIO *bp_public = NULL;
  RSA *pubkey;
  bp_public = BIO_new_file("public.pem", "rt");
  pubkey = PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey(bp_public, &rsa, NULL, NULL);

  BIO * keybio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
  RSA_print(keybio, rsa, 0);
  char buffer [2048];

  while (BIO_read (keybio, buffer, 2048) > 0)
    {
      printf("%s", buffer);
    }
  BIO_free(bp_public);
  if (pubkey == NULL || rsa == NULL)
    printf("Something went wrong");

  char msg[] = "Hello";
  unsigned char * encrypted = NULL;

  RSA_public_encrypt(5, (unsigned char *)msg, encrypted, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);

  printf("Here: %s", encrypted);
}
```

Also, I tried using both `pubkey` and `rsa` as the key and none worked.

I am sure I am missing something pretty obvious, but I have spent hours behind it and I am kinda lost in the openssl docs now.

Thanks for the help!

Irrelevant note: The encrypted text returns null if I use `RSA_private_encrypt()`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala uhh, sorry. I missed em while copying them, there was an unused function which I had to omit and missed the includes in the process. Thanks for reminding me. :)

Comment: BIO_read doesn't seem like you could print it with `%s`...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Well, this works for me, it seems. This is what I get: http://pasted.co/682d8a0d

Comment: How do you suppose null pointer works for the parameter to `RSA_public_encrypt`

Comment: Oh, looks like doing `unsigned char encrypted[RSA_size(rsa)];` instead of setting it to `NULL` actually encrypted the text.

Comment: Next time: `valgrind` is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`RSA_public_encrypt`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rsa_public_encrypt):

> ```
> int RSA_public_encrypt(int flen, unsigned char *from,
>    unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);
> ```
>
> `RSA_public_encrypt()` encrypts the `flen` bytes at from (usually a session key) using the public key `rsa` and stores the ciphertext in `to`. `to` must point to `RSA_size(rsa)` bytes of memory.

yet you have `to` parameter as

```
unsigned char * encrypted = NULL;
```

Perhaps you should *allocate* `RSA_size(rsa)` bytes of memory for it:

```
unsigned char *encrypted = malloc(RSA_size(rsa));
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried myself. Thanks, I will once verify the output by decrypting it with the public key.

Comment: @dedipyaman You also don't want to print the encrypted string with `%s`, because it's binary data, not a string.  You instead want to loop over the bytes and print each one individually.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you manage various Openssl resources properly. Often times, There would be restrictions on what can be freed. Freeing resources early on might cause a segfault elsewhere in the library.